# Breaks the product based on ${x_j}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinations

Can anyone help me to break this product into the series based on ${x_j}$ ?

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{K}(1-x_i)$$

I want to break it to some function as below:

$$ \sum_j\Psi(x_j)  $$

I saw something like this long time ago in an article, but I cant remember it right now! I appreciate any suggestion for starting point! or any hint.

Comment: I guess you mean $x^i$ in the product?

Comment: In your product there are $K$ numbers $x_1, \dots x_K$ but no $x$!

Comment: have you tried to derive a formula for $K=1,K=2$ etc. and find a pattern?

Comment: @ Surb, yes it does not make sense ! maybe i made mistake

Comment: @gammatester oh sorry , i am editing

Comment: Your edit will be hard to reach, since there are mixed terms appearing in your product. E.g. $K=2 \implies  (1-x_1)(1-x_2)=1-x_1-x_2+{\color{red}{x_1x_2}}$

Comment: i was confused with my thoughts, i am really sorry !

Comment: ok , consider this new edit

Comment: A formula of the form $\sum_{j}\prod_{\text{cyc}}$ could be possible.

Comment: that is the question cyclic definition.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something along the lines of considering the logarithm of the product, whence
\begin{eqnarray}
\log \prod_{i=1}^{K}(1-x_{i}) &=& \sum_{i=1}^{K}\log(1-x_{i})
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: and if i break the right hand side log we have log(PROD), haven't I ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by break but I imagine it would be difficult to find a function $\Psi$ since asymptotically you could consider the Taylor expansions of $\log (1-x_{i})$ etc

Comment: you solution gives the logarithm of a product. ok ? but i want a new representation of a products to sums